# Find a Taylor polynomial approximation of

Tags: calculus

Find a Taylor polynomial approximation of 
$ \ f(x)=\large \frac{1}{x} \int_0^x \frac{dt}{1+t^3} \ $ of degree $ \ 3 \ $ or larger , centered at $ \ a=0 \ $

Estimate $ \ f(0.1) \ $ and find the upper bound of error.

**Answer:**

$ \ f(x)=\large \frac{1}{x} \int_0^x \frac{dt}{1+t^3}  $

The anti-derivative of $ \ f(x) \ $ is involving again an integral sign as follows

$ \frac{d}{dx} f(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2}\int_{0}^{x} \frac{dt}{1+t^3} +\frac{1}{x(1+x^3)}-\frac{1}{x} $

This becomes critical to expand as series.

I need help doing this.

Comment: We have to use Taylor series approximation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First multiply $x$ on both sides.

$x$ $f(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{dt}{1+t^3}$
$f(x)+x$ $f'(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^3}$ $ $ $ $ $f(0)= 1$
$2f'(x)+xf''(x)=-3x^2(1+x^3)^{-2}$ $ $ $f'(0)=0$

$f''(0)=0$
$f'''(0)=-\frac{3}{2}$
$f(x)=1-\frac{1}{4}x^3$

$f(0.1)=0.99975$